# how to extract a substring from a string, if the length of string is unknown

Tags: c

Lets say I have 
`string1 = "DDD DXXXX"
string2 = "DDXXXX"
string3 = "DXXXX"`

and if i want to extract XXXX all the time, then what is the best way in c? substr, strncpy, strndup everything needs a starting position.

Is regex the only option?

Comment: By extract do you mean remove from the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strstr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/) to locate the `"XXXX"`:

```
char string1[] = "DDXXXX";
char* xxxx_ptr = strstr(string1, "XXXX");
if (xxxx_ptr)
{
    /* Do something. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know it is always at the end and of a fixed length, you can calculate its starting position by calculating the length of the string (`strlen()`) and subtracting the fixed length.

This assumes the substring is always part of the strings you examine

Comment: No, the string length that follows the target substring is variable.

Comment: That means it must conform to a pattern that you can check.  in this case regex is probably a good general tool to attack the problem with